# How to pass date value using Jquery UI+Laravel

Tags: jquery, date, laravel-4, datepicker

My problem is that I get 0000-00-00 00:00:00 value.
My input field:

```
    <input id="datepicker2" type="text" name="unload_date">
    $(function () {
    $("#datepicker1").datepicker({
     format: "dd MM yyyy",}
    );
 $("#datepicker2").datepicker({
 format: "dd MM yyyy",
                            });});
```

The problem is that I want to pass only date to my database as value. 
My migrations looks like this.

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('load_target', 255);
            $table->dateTime('load_date');
            $table->string('unload_target', 255);
            $table->dateTime('unload_date');}}
```

The timestamps works perfectly, but why I can't pass my values to (load_date, unload_date)

I am using EloQentORM saving

```
$order->unload_date=Input::get('unload_date');
$order->save();
```

How to solve this? What time format should I take or use specific tool, lib?

I want to pass my yyyy MM dd value to MySql database.

Please leave an idea where to look for problems?

---

I found this:
`$order->unload_date=date("Y-m-d",strtotime(Input::get('unload_date));`

Is this good solution? are there shorter solutions?
By the way I changed:
`format:"yyyy-mm-dd"` in Jquery

Comment: how does `Input::get('unload_date');` value look like ? I solved the exact same problem. Maybe I can help

Answer (score 0):

use `Datetime` to format your date.

for best practise put the following code to your `order` model.

```
public function setUnloadDateAttribute($date)
{
    $datetime = new DateTime();
    $datetime->createFromFormat('d m Y', $date);
    $this->attributes['unload_date'] = $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```

Comment: But my date value comes from datepicker input for unload_date 10/04/2015, but it wont go correctly to my database, for example laravel timestamps() created at goes perfectly, but it gives only time reated and updated.

Comment: After line it is working thing, but in future i need to make calculations with that value, and seeking for better idea, how to pass that value?